# Matplotlib: how to fix label width independent of label content

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want the position of the graph to be consistent over multiple plots. However the position depends on the width of the tick labels on the y-axis.
I can limit the text length to e.g. 8 characters, however due to the different character width the position of the graphs origin still changes.

How can I fix the tick label width or the plots origin position?

[image][image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Insert a line break #EVERY characters
def insert_linebreak(string, every=8):
    lines = []
    for i in range(0, len(string), every):
        lines.append(string[i:i+every])
    return '\n'.join(lines)

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


plt.rcdefaults()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Example data
people = ('.........', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
people_fixed_length=[]
for i in range(len(people)):
    people_fixed_length.append(insert_linebreak(people[i]))
people=people_fixed_length
    
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error = np.random.rand(len(people))

ax.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos, labels=people)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
ax.set_xlabel('Performance')
ax.set_title('How fast do you want to go today?')

plt.show()


plt.rcdefaults()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Example data
people = ('MMMMMMMMMM', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
people_fixed_length=[]
for i in range(len(people)):
    people_fixed_length.append(insert_linebreak(people[i]))
people=people_fixed_length
    
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error = np.random.rand(len(people))

ax.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos, labels=people)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
ax.set_xlabel('Performance')
ax.set_title('How fast do you want to go today?')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Why don't you use a figure with all graphs as axes? The plots will be aligned automatically

Comment: The figures are placed in a PDF and each figure is already a full page. When looking through the PDF the charts "jump" right now...

Comment: You could try `plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15, right=0.97)` (using fixed values that work well for you), Don't use `bbox_inches='tight` while saving.